# Does next.js fetch the entire app when the first request is made?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

From what I've read online it sounds like Nextjs uses client side routing which means that on the first request, every page will be fetched from the server, and then on subsequent requests, those pages get rendered on the browser without needing to talk to the server. My question though is, where are these pages on my browser? I can only see my login page under the chrome sources tab, but I also have a signup and dashboard page that I don't see anywhere.
[image]

And secondly, if nextjs is using client side routing, does that mean none of my server routes should serve webpages, but rather it should just be acting as an api for working with data? Except for possibly one route, which can serve the initial request?

Comment: So one specific example I have that is confusing me, is that on my login page, I do a redirect to the dashboard using router.push(/Dashboard) if the user successfully logs in. And I can see that this code does not make a server request. As well, I don't see the dashboard page in the browser... So where is it getting the page from?

Comment: Which randomly named pages though? I've expanded the entire relevant source tree in the picture above, so I'm not sure which file could possibly contain the code for my dashboard

Comment: No, I've just been running locally with "node server.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question though is, where are these pages on my browser? I can only see my login page under the chrome sources tab, but I also have a signup and dashboard page that I don't see anywhere.

Since you are in development mode, the chunks will only be processed and sent to the browser when you are navigating - If you use a dynamic import and in production mode you will see it on route change.

> And secondly, if nextjs is using client side routing, does that mean none of my server routes should serve webpages, but rather it should just be acting as an api for working with data? Except for possibly one route, which can serve the initial request?

For this topic, i would ask that you review Pre-rendering and how it works and familiarize yourself with SSG and SSR - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages

Comment: I have read that link a lot of times actually, but I'm confused as to when next would actually render the entire page on the server side. For example my dashboard page uses the getServerSideProps method, and I can see that function is being called on the server, but there is no actual get request to my server to fetch the dashboard page. The request to my server is only to fetch the props. Is there an instance in which the entire page would be fetched?

Comment: Yes, when the route is directly accessed on the browser - depending on how you have it setup pre generated or SSR you will get a full page back